# How to remove characters from filenames in R?

Tags: r, character, rename, filenames

Due to an unrelated software error I have many files with double filenames e.g.

```
c("info10_file1.info10_file1.xy", "info11_file1.info11_file1.xy")
```

I want to remove this repetition, The files should be:

```
c("info10_file1.xy", "info11_file1.xy")
```

I have tried using `sapply` for a file rename function, but that requires a pattern which means only patterns with `info10` will be changed.

So running this code:

```
sapply(files_list,FUN=function(eachPath){
....file.rename(from=eachPath,to=sub(pattern='info10_file1.',replacement='',eachPath))
})
```

Will result in:

```
"info10_file1.xy", "info11_file1.info11_file1.xy"
```

An improvement can be done by setting `pattern='file1.info'` which means all files will be processed, but the number 10 or 11 in info10 or info11 will still be repeated producing this:

```
"info10_10_file1.xy", "info11_11_file1.xy"
```

Is there a way to simply delete an arbitrary amount of characters? In this example it would be 13.

Comment: If `x` is the vector containing your file names, try `y<-sub("^[^\\.]*\\.","",x)` and then (if `y` is what you intended) `file.rename(x,y)`.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly.